# What is a closed path in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that line integral of $f(x,y,z)=(y,x,x)$ around a closed path in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not $0$

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, unit circle is a great example for closed path, but I don't know what a closed path is in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Hint: $\phi(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0),\,\,t\in [0,2\pi)$ a circle in XY-plane

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer, please check if I didn't change anything important.

Comment: Oh, So I can consider the same region as I did in R^2?

Comment: To Suhail, I got still 0 for that path.

Comment: Try a circle in the xz plane.

Comment: $\phi(t)=(a\cos t,b\sin t,0), t\in[0,2\pi)$ an ellipse in XY-plane with suitable values of $a$ and $b.$